# How to extract data between two delimiters '|' from a text file using getline function in c++?

Tags: c++, delimiter, getline

There's data arranged between delimiters in a file which looks like this:
|  No. |  name. |  product. |  price. |
I want to read one data at a time.
Each section partitioned by these delimiters contains one or more syllables (one or few words). How to I read this ?

Comment: You called it. `getline(stream, token, '|')` will get you everything from the start to the first |, between two |s or from the last | to the end of the stream.

Comment: Or, better, read the entire line and then use `stingstream s (line)` and then `while (getline (s, val, '|'))` so you do not read more than 1 line of data at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach for a delimited file would be to read the entire line into a `string`, then create a `stringstream` from the line and loop over the stringstream calling `getline` with the delimiter (`'|'` here) to separate the value into the fields.

(this way the number of fields need not be known ahead of time -- without `stringstream` you must limit your read of fields to the number present using `getline` or `getline` will happily begin reading data from the next line)

Below the example just reads each field of the input file into a `string`, but for your needs you may want an additional conversion, (e.g. `stol` or the like) to convert the individual fields to `int` or `double` (that is left to you).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    string line;

    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "error: usage, program <filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream f (argv[1]);   /* open file */
    if (!f.is_open()) {     /* validate file open for reading */
        perror (("error while opening file " + string(argv[1])).c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (f, line)) {         /* read each line */
        string val;                     /* string to hold value */
        stringstream s (line);          /* stringstream to parse fields */
        /* output original line */
        cout << "line: " << line << "\n\n";
        /* skip 1st delim */
        s.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '|');
        while (getline (s, val, '|'))   /* for each field */
            cout << "  value: " << val << '\n'; /* output each field value */
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/fields.txt
| 1   | Joe   | marbles  |   1.25 |
| 2   | Mike  | jacks    |  13.49 |
| 3   | Jill  | pail     |   4.50 |
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/iostream_strstream_fields dat/fields.txt
line: | 1   | Joe   | marbles  |   1.25 |

  value:  1
  value:  Joe
  value:  marbles
  value:    1.25

line: | 2   | Mike  | jacks    |  13.49 |

  value:  2
  value:  Mike
  value:  jacks
  value:   13.49

line: | 3   | Jill  | pail     |   4.50 |

  value:  3
  value:  Jill
  value:  pail
  value:    4.50
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Rewrite in C for 32-year old Operating System**

Since you are attempting to compile with a still unidentified C++ compiler on a 32 year old operating system, (none of which was specified in your original question), you are probably much better served writing your parse routine in C. Why? The C++ standard was very amorphous at that time. It was more a superset of C then compared to what C++ is today. In the Turbo C and Borland C++ compilers of that day, all included files still used the C header file include format (which contain the `'.h'` at the end of the header name, e.g. `#include <string.h>`) This explains your "failure to find header" issue.

C on the otherhand was much closer to what is available today. Though it has gone through several standard revisions, the basic function available then and now are the same. The following has a much better chance at compiling on whatever you have DOS 3.2 running on that the C++ code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FLDSZ 32   /* maximum file size for name and product */
#define MAXC 256   /* maximum length for line (including '\0') */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";    /* buffer to hold each line */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
        int id;                     /* id from file */
        char name[FLDSZ] = "",      /* name */
            product[FLDSZ] = "";    /* product */
        float price;                /* price */
        size_t len = strlen (buf);  /* length of string in buffer */
        if (len == MAXC - 1 && buf[len - 1] != '\n') {  /* check it fit */
            fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf (buf, "|%d | %31s | %31s | %f",      /* parse fields */
                    &id, name, product, &price) != 4) {
            fputs ("error: failed to parse line.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        /* output parsed fields */
        printf ("%3d %-10s %-10s %.2f\n", id, name, product, price);
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

(the program expects the data filename as the 1st argument, or it will read from `stdin` if no argument is given)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fieldparse ~/dev/src-cpp/tmp/dat/fields.txt
  1 Joe        marbles    1.25
  2 Mike       jacks      13.49
  3 Jill       pail       4.50
```

All I can tell you is give it a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: thank you sir. but the problem is my editor does not support some functions as it does not recognise the header files. can you give any other alternative ??

Comment: What compiler? (those are all C++-standard headers.) What does your compiler say is not recognized? Can you compile with the `-std=C++11` option?

Comment: @VinitaKumari I have compiled on both Linux and Windows7 (old VS) and it compiles and runs fine on both. I can't image you have something older than Win7?

Comment: no, actually i m using ms dos to write my c++ program

Comment: Oh, like Borland C++ days? What version of MSDOS? I used to use Borland on DOS 4.1 (got rid of the 33M partition limit from DOS 3.X). What compiler are you using so I can look up what it has? (oh, goodness, that was for my 386DX with Math Co-Processor) The only header I can think of that wouldn't be there is `<limits>` is that what your compiler can't find? Let me know.

Comment: ms dos 3.2, the same inbuilt compiler

Comment: This one [Borland for Dox 3.x](https://winworldpc.com/product/turbo-c/3x)?? Dos 3.2 is from 1986 - 32 years ago. It came on 5.25 inch floppies. (yes I still have many) You can't get anything newer than that?? If I were dealing with something that old, I write in C, not C++. C++ was just being developed.

Comment: Also note at that time the C++ include files still required the `'.h'` at the end (e.g. `#include <string.h>`) -- long, long ago.