# How to create a function to read from a text file in C++ and ignore certain character and store data values in appropriate variables?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have the `class date` defined as follows. I have programed the function `write(ostream &o)` to write the date in this format `27/May/2020` so its easily readable to the user. Now i want to read from a file containing the date in aforementioned format. So how do i write a function in C++ that would ignore the `'/'` character and store the value `27` for example in `int day`, the value `"May"` in `string month` and the value `2010` in `int year`. Also how can i design a function to ignore a certain character and be able to store the values in various data types in C++?

```
class date{
    private :
        int day;
        string month;
        int year;

        public:
            date()
            {
                day=0;
                month="NULL";
                year=2020;
            }

            void getdate()
            {
                cout<<"Enter Date : ";
                cin>>day>>month;
            }

            void write(ostream &o) const  // to write text file or screen
            {
                o<<day<<'/'<<month.c_str()<<'/'<<year;
            }

};
```

Comment: The third argument of [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) seems like it would be pretty handy for this. What you're asking is how to extract *delimited* data, and there are many duplicates  on site, such as the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302355/how-to-extract-data-or-read-data-from-a-file-between-two-delimiters-using), found searching `[cpp] delimited data`

Comment: @WhozCraig Would `std::getline` also be able to store data in various types as well or will treat all data as `char`?

Comment: It reads `std::string` content, delimited by that additional argument, whose default value is `'\n'`. If you want native types, first read into a `std::string`, then use the `std::stoX` functions (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)) , or load into a `std::istringstream` and use formatted extraction, similar to what you're probably used to already.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hmmm... im only familiar with `getline`. i would have to read about those functions. i will look into it. Thanks a lot for the reference!

Comment: @WhozCraig `istringstream` would help with this. Thank again for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a very simple approach, using the property of stream extraction/insertion operators return a reference to the stream. With that you can chain extraction statement like in your example `cin>>day>>month;`.

With that you can do a one liner, like in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss{"27/May/2020"};

int main() {

    int day{};
    std::string month{};
    int year{};
    char slash{};

    if ((std::getline(iss >> day >> slash, month, '/') >> year) && (slash == '/')) {

        std::cout << day << ' ' << month << ' ' << year << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nError: Wrong input format\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

OP asked for more explanation for the one liner.

```
if ((std::getline(iss >> day >> slash, month, '/') >> year) && (slash == '/')) {
```

OK. As you know, nested functions will be evaluated from inside out. If you have for example: `pow(sqrt(x+100),y+2)`, then at first x+100, then sqrt then y+2 and finally pow will be evaluated. Good, understood.

Looking at our one liner, it means, first `iss >> day` will be evaluated. In the open stream iss (you can also use `std::cin` or an `std::ifstream` or basically any `istream`) we have at the beginning: "27/May/2020". The above extraction operation will extract the digits 2 and 7 and convert it to the integer 27. That is our day.

Now, the input stream contains "/May/2020" because the 2 and the 7 have already been extracted.

The operation `iss >> day` is finished now. The overloaded extractor operator `>>` will always return a reference to the `istream` with which it was invoked. Meaning, `iss >> day` will return "iss".

The prototype of such a operator is usually defined as

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, SomeClass& sc) { 
    // Do something with SomeClass sc . . .
    return is; }
```

You can see, that the stream is returned. And that gives you the possibility to chain the extractor operator. After this first `iss >> day` statement has been evaluated, the rest of the line would look like:

```
 if ((std::getline(iss >> slash, month, '/') >> year) && (slash == '/'))
```

because `iss >> day` has been done and returned iss. Remember that our stream contains "/May/2020" now. And, next we will do: `iss >> slash`. Meaning, we will extract the slash from the stream and store it in the variable slash. The extractor operator will again return iss. And the data in the stream is now "May/2020". The new one liner will be:

```
if ((std::getline(iss, month, '/') >> year) && (slash == '/'))
```

This we can understand. `std::getline will extract a string from the stream, until it sees a slash. That string is stored in the variable month. The data in the stream will now be "2020". And guest what?`std::getline```` will also return a reference to the given stream. With that the one liner will now be

```
 if ((iss >> year) && (slash == '/'))
```

We know, what will come now: `iss >> year` will be evaluated. "2020" will be converted to the integer 2020. The stream is now empty. Everything has been extracted. The operator `>>`will again return iss. Giving us:

```
if ((iss) && (slash == '/'))
```

Hm, `if` expects a boolean expression, how does this work with iss? Can be explained: If expects a boolean expression and, very smart, a stream as an overloaded bool operator. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). And this operator returns, if the stream is in good state or failed.

If some extraction operation in the whole chain would have failed, then the bool operator would return false. And then we would show the error message.

As an additional check, we validate the contents of the variable "slash".

So, that's it. I hope, i could explain it in an understandable way.

---

**End EDIT**

---

But maybe it is more safe, if you first read a complete line (`std::string` with `std::getline` and then split this line.

I will show you some example code for this as well.

See some common patterns for splitting a string:

Splitting a string into tokens is a very old task. There are many many solutions available. All have different properties. Some are difficult to understand, some are hard to develop, some are more complex, slower or faster or more flexible or not.

Alternatives

1. Handcrafted, many variants, using pointers or iterators,  maybe hard to develop and error prone.
2. Using old style `std::strtok` function. Maybe unsafe. Maybe should not be used any longer
3. `std::getline`. Most used implementation. But actually a "misuse" and not so flexible
4. Using dedicated modern function, specifically developed for this purpose, most flexible and good fitting into the STL environment and algortithm landscape. But slower.

Please see 4 examples in one piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <forward_list>
#include <deque>

using Container = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex delimiter{ "," };


int main() {

    // Some function to print the contents of an STL container
    auto print = [](const auto& container) -> void { std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::decay<decltype(*container.begin())>::type>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; };

    // Example 1:   Handcrafted -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Search for comma, then take the part and add to the result
        for (size_t i{ 0U }, startpos{ 0U }; i <= stringToSplit.size(); ++i) {

            // So, if there is a comma or the end of the string
            if ((stringToSplit[i] == ',') || (i == (stringToSplit.size()))) {

                // Copy substring
                c.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(startpos, i - startpos));
                startpos = i + 1;
            }
        }
        print(c);
    }

    // Example 2:   Using very old strtok function ----------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Split string into parts in a simple for loop
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        for (char* token = std::strtok(const_cast<char*>(stringToSplit.data()), ","); token != nullptr; token = std::strtok(nullptr, ",")) {
            c.push_back(token);
        }

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 3:   Very often used std::getline with additional istringstream ------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Put string in an std::istringstream
        std::istringstream iss{ stringToSplit };

        // Extract string parts in simple for loop
        for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); c.push_back(part))
            ;

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 4:   Most flexible iterator solution  ------------------------------------------------

    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };


        Container c(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
        //
        // Everything done already with range constructor. No additional code needed.
        //

        print(c);


        // Works also with other containers in the same way
        std::forward_list<std::string> c2(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

        print(c2);

        // And works with algorithms
        std::deque<std::string> c3{};
        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c3));

        print(c3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Woww. Great answer. Lots of code so i will go through it slowly so i understand every single bit of it. I am not so familiars with `STL containers` so i will stick to using `getline`.
Ca you explain this code in the first code sample above? `if ((std::getline(iss >> day >> slash, month, '/') >> year) && (slash == '/'))` in detail please?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma: I added a detailed explanation

Comment: That helps a lot. I complete understand it now. Thank so much!

Comment: Can you please tell me any time we store something from a stream to a variable i.e. we `extract from stream` the stream doesn't contain the `extracted characters anymore`, is it true?